# How to get a list of posts Facebook user posted through my app

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I want to know how to get list of posts or share done by user to his facebook wall through my app.

Regards,
Jeeva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using FQL in the Graph API explorer you can get it this way:

```
fql?q=SELECT post_id, type, message, description, created_time, app_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND app_id = '5085647995'
```

This returns all posts on your timeline by the Hulu app. Replace this with your app_id.

Keep in mind that the `stream` object only returns up to 30 days worth or 50 posts by default.

Comment: is there is any way to get list of posts done through my app id , some thing like activity.

Comment: is there is any way to get list of posts done through my app id , some thing like activity

Comment: Not without knowing a each user's id. Facebook has gone through a deliberate process of removing the ability of page and app owners to find out who is using the app.